# Once option selected from select dropdown list, append it to a div on button click

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, append

I have a select dropdown and a button. Once you select an item from the select dropdown and click the button, I need the selected item to get appended to a div which displays what you added.

You should be able to keep selecting and adding items to the div. Also the options which you add should have an X next to them which you can use to delete them from the selection list.

I need to figure out how to write the JQuery for this. Please help! Thanks!

Here is an image of what I need it to look like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-7">
    <span>Select the fixture type:*</span>
          <select id="fixture-type">
                 <option>Select</option>
                 <option>Select</option>
                 <option>Select</option>
          </select>
    <button class="btn-primary">+ ADD FEATURE</button>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5">
     <div class="append-list">
     <!--Append selection box items here-->
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fixture-type").on('change', function (e){
        $(".append-list").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have done research. I am not well versed in JQuery. The code I have for my JQuery is listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-7">
    <span>Select the fixture type:*</span>
          <select id="fixture-type">
                 <option>Select1</option>
                 <option>Select2</option>
                 <option>Select3</option>
          </select>
    <button class="btn-primary" id="mybtn">+ ADD FEATURE</button>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5">
     <div class="append-list ul">
     <!--Append selection box items here-->
     </div>
</div>

$('#mybtn').click(function(){
    $(".append-list").append('<li>'+ $('#fixture-type').val() +'</li>');

});
```

I have working solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g0g98wvp/) for your

Please let me know, if helps.